# I want to use differentials in ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My goal was to create TimeStamps to make a simple differentiation. I don't know yet how to use ros::Time.

This my pd_controller node:

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include "pd_controller/Int32Stamped.h"
#include <math.h>

pd_controller::Int32Stamped encoder;

ros::Subscriber encoder_sub;
ros::Publisher vel_pub;
geometry_msgs::Twist vel;       

// subscriber from comm encoder
void encoderCallback(const pd_controller::Int32Stamped::ConstPtr& tk){

//Modify this equation to be the Controller Function
    // double timelapse[10] = {0};
   double timelapse = encoder.header.stamp.toSec() -encoder.header.stamp.toSec();
   double kd = (double(encoder.data) - double(encoder.data))/timelapse;
   vel.linear.x = float(((encoder.data*234)*5886) + kd);
   encoder.data = tk->data;
   encoder.header = tk->header; 
   vel_pub.publish(vel);
}


//make publisher for cmd_vel

//create a rotary encoder to send cmd_vel

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv, "pd_controller");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   vel_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);
   encoder_sub = nh.subscribe<pd_controller::Int32Stamped> ("comm_encoder", 10, &encoderCallback); 
        

   ros::spin();

   return 0;
}
```

When I run the code I get as output in cmd_vel the value: **nan**

How do I properly set a differential equation in ROS????
I just want after_topic - before_topic divided by the time difference between these topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268590/i-want-to-use-differentials-in-ros/) by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I recall correctly, from your [previous question](https://answers.ros.org/question/268349/error-implementing-ros-timer/?comment=268591#post-id-268591) you defined `surp::Int32Stamped` to be

```
Header header
int32 data
```

The `header` portion of your message has a `stamp` attribute which carries the time, as you know. According to the wiki, the way that you [convert from `ros::Duration` to floating point](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Converting_Time_and_Duration_Instances) is by using the `toSec()` method, not by casting. For example:

```
double secs =ros::Time::now().toSec();

ros::Duration d(0.5);
secs = d.toSec();
```

Therefore, you should change

```
double timelapse = double(encoder.header.stamp) - double(encoder.header.stamp);
```

to

```
double timelapse = encoder.header.stamp.toSec() - encoder.header.stamp.toSec();
```

But, this raises another issue. Isn't this just going to be zero...

---

**Edit:**

If I'm understanding you correctly, should either use a global (easiest, not necessarily the best way) to keep track of the previous time that the callback was called or use a class and have an attribute that does that.

I've used the `...` for brevity, but here's an example (using a global):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

...

double previous_time;

// subscriber from comm encoder
void encoderCallback(const surp::Int32Stamped::ConstPtr& tk){

  //Modify this equation to be the Controller Function
  double timelapse = encoder.header.stamp.toSec() - previous_time;
  previous_time = encoder.header.stamp.toSec();

...

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv, "pd_controller");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   vel_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);
   encoder_sub = nh.subscribe<std_msgs::Int32> ("comm_encoder", 10, &encoderCallback); 

   previous_time = ros::Time::now().toSec();

   ros::spin();

   return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-11**:
I finally understood how Header works. I corrected it few minnutes after I posted here.
The main issue is how to do a differential in ROS. If I uderstand it everything else that follows will be easy, like integrals, sensor fusion, ...etc.
Yes, it is 0, and gives me **nan**
how do I do it right?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-11**:
Can you update your question with that output?

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-11**:
Ok, it worked. Now I need to explore how to tweek it, because it is not generating the right output.
Probably topic for another questions.
Someone need to write a tutorial on how to create controllers following the Ogata book.
Teach from PID to LQR and LQG.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-11**:
I believe that questions regarding how to write controllers would be out of the scope of this site (as it's not ROS specific). It would be better asked on a site like [Stack Overlfow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-13**:
I strongly disagree to you jayess, people who apply ROS has intention in building robots. Controllers are ultimately what enables you go from simple robots to real cool ones. Controllers are extremely important and is very sad the fact there is no tutorial on ROS wiki.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-13**:
I agree that controllers are important to robotics and engineering in general. However, this site is for *ROS-related* questions. There are other sites dedicated to questions about robotics in general such as [Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time

Subtracting a stamp (ros::Time) from a stamp produces a ros::Duration, which has to be converted to a double:

```
ros::Duration d(0.5);
double secs = d.toSec()
```

I don't understand how there isn't a different error message for the code you posted though, either double(timestamp) should produce an error, or timelapse is a double and there would be no error for it.

It looks like you want to subtract encoder.data from tk.data and similar for the timestamps, otherwise you are going to get a divide by zero, and zero in the numerator besides.

Hopefully the error here is obvious:

```
encoder.header.stamp = tk->header;
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-11**:
but how do I do the differentiation?? It is giving me **nan**
How do I do after_topic - before_topic and divide by the time difference ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to copy the header from one message into the timestamp in another message, and the compiler is trying to tell you that these types aren't compatible.

The relevant error message is:

```
home/rmb/gopigo_ws/src/pd_controller/src/pd_controller.cpp:24:25: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void> >::_stamp_type {aka ros::Time}’ and ‘const _header_type {aka const std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void> >}’)
encoder.header.stamp = tk->header;
```

It looks like you should update that line so that it's just copying the timestamp:

```
encoder.header.stamp = tk->header.stamp;
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1